# How to extract parameters from a URL regardless the way it written by?

Tags: java, url, http-post, url-parameters, query-string

I want a java way to extract the parameters of a URL regardless the way these parameters are written in it, in the regular way like( https://www.facebook.com/Doly.mohamed.Smile9?ref=stream&hc_location=stream ) it's so easy because all i have to do is :

```
URL url = new URL("www.blabla....etc");

String query = url.getQuery();

try{
String [] params = query.split("&");

for(int i= 0 ; i < params.length; i++){
    String [] split = params[i].split("=");
    parameters.put(split[0], split[1]);
}
}catch(NullPointerException ex){}
```

so the parameters values would be :

```
key = ref  value = stream ,  key = hc_location value = stream
```

but what shall i do if the URL has parameters written in another way or if the URL does't has it's parameters written in it like in the case of the `doPost()` way.

and is there is a way to get the extraPathInfo from a URL without using servlets?

Comment: In the case of POST data there is no generic way to parse parameters. POST data can be anything - even a serialized java object. You have to know what you _expect_ to be getting and parse that. Return some error code if the parsing doesn't work.

Comment: there is no standard way the parameters written in http body in it ?

Answer (score 3):

You could do that easily with Apache's HTTP utils.

```
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(uriString);
List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = uriBuilder.getQueryParams();
String uriWithoutParameters = uriBuilder.clearParameters().toString();
```

Now you could, for example, easily convert the GET request to a POST request, using other classes from the http utils API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between **GET** and **POST** urls

In **GET** url, parameters are part of URL and in [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) they are part of Request-body.

So in **POST**, the URL **may** or **may not** contain the **request params**, and unless you don't have them in the URL its not possible to extract.

> The POST request method is designed to request that a web server
> accept the data enclosed in the request message's body for storage.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)
> It is often used when uploading a file or submitting a completed web
> form.

So unless you have the POST request's body. Its difficult to extract the Parameter.

Comment: but there is a way to get the post request and analysing it ? and also are know a way to get the (extra path info) from a URL without using servlets?

Comment: Basically a HTTP request is a string, written in some protocal. and a URL is an address. With a POST URL u can't find the params, but with the whole POST request you can. Thats what I was trying to explain

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need HTTP request parameters on HTTP server side. Java HTTP server will parse the request and pass it as ServletRequest object to Servlet.service method. ServletRequest has methods to access the request parameters.