# How can i extract a specific item with split function

Tags: java

It's possible to extract a specific item in String with split function

***example:***

```
offers/BESTOFFERS/FRTNE/FRPAR/2015-01-05?passengers=STANDARD:1&returnDate=2015-01-12&maxVia=0&withThac=false
```

i want to extract just `returnDate`

***ouptut why i want:***

> 2015-01-12

OR

i want to extract just `passengers`

***ouptut why i want:***

> STANDARD:1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22191247/1927832   might help

Comment: SO is not to write code for you.. Show us what you have tried, where you failed. what error you got.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract parameters from a given url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902090/how-to-extract-parameters-from-a-given-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to stick on the split method you could solve it for example like this

```
String str = "offers/BESTOFFERS/FRTNE/FRPAR/2015-01-05?passengers=STANDARD:1&returnDate=2015-01-12&maxVia=0&withThac=false";
int paramDelim = str.indexOf('?');
String parmeters = str.substring(paramDelim + 1, str.length());
String[] parts = parmeters.split("[&=]");
System.out.println("parts = " + Arrays.toString(parts));
```

`parts` contain the paramer names (odd entries) and the values (even entries).

If you don't need to stick on the split method try one of the proposed URL parser solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below approach of using HashMap

```
void populateMap()
{
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String uri = "offers/BESTOFFERS/FRTNE/FRPAR/2015-01-05?passengers=STANDARD:1&returnDate=2015-01-12&maxVia=0&withThac=false";
    int len = uri.indexOf('?');
    String input = str.substring(len + 1, uri.length());
    for(String retVal : input.split("&")
    {
        String[] innerRet = retVal.split(":");
        myMap.put(innerRet[0],innerRet[1]);
    }
}

String retValue (String key)
{
    return myMap.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    String str = "offers/BESTOFFERS/FRTNE/FRPAR/2015-01-05?passengers=STANDARD:1&returnDate=2015-01-12&maxVia=0&withThac=false";

    String returnDate = str.split("&")[1].replaceAll
    ("returnDate=","").trim();

    String passengers= str.split("?")[1].split("&")[0].replaceAll
    ("passengers=","").trim();
```

Comment: Any reason why you've chosen not to recommend a standard URL parser?

Comment: @Bathsheba : User has asked to achieve it using String split() function.

Comment: Let's hope he never changes the order of these name/value-pairs.

Comment: True, but you'd be wise to advise against it.